# trying to pull all the user names who modified a particular record

Tags: apex, custom-object, query

there is no existing field which can show me who all modified the record & filed tracking is disabled. Is there any other way I can pull the data who modified a particular record. Not looking for last modified but list of all modified users. any query which can help me to pull data? thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have [History Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en) on the key fields enabled then you would not be able to do this in Salesforce.

You can track User logins by default using the [login history](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_login_history.htm) and configuration changes using the [setup audit trail](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_monitorsetup.htm&language=en), but with each record only changes on fields with history tracking enabled would be logged.